# WPF Change color of Rectangle placed inside Button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, controltemplate, shapes

I've got a `rectangle` in a `button` and want to change it's color. How can i Do that?

```
<Button Click="btnInitial_Click" Margin="0, 5, 0,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Name="btnInitial">
       <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Name="rectInitial" Stroke="Black" Fill="#4169e1"></Rectangle>
            </ControlTemplate>
       </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

//EDIT:
I want to change it in its own Click Event.

Comment: do you want to change color from codebehind?

Comment: Yes, i want to do that in codebehind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do so, depending on where you want to set it. If you want to set it from code-behind you can to it like this:

```
var rect = btnInitial.Template.FindName("rectInitial") as Rectangle;
rect.Fill = Brushes.Aquamarine;
```

Comment: @Giraffe My bad I had misplaced the name. it should work now.

Comment: Nope. You forgot the second parameter of "FindName":   `var rect = btnBackground.Template.FindName("rectBackground", btnBackground) as Rectangle;`

Comment: @Giraffe That also. Sorry wrote it down from memory :P